# Using openapi-generator-cli inside a devcontainer

Tags: openapi-generator, openapi-generator-cli, devcontainer

I am trying to run [openapi-generator-cli](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator#16---docker) from a devcontainer. Here are the files I used :

```
// .devcontainer/devcontainer.json
{
  "name": "OpenAPI DevContainer",
  "dockerFile": "Dockerfile",
  "mounts": [
     "source=${localWorkspaceFolder}/openapi_specs,target=/workspaces/openapi_specs,type=bind,consistency=cached",
     "source=${localWorkspaceFolder}/my_client_library,target=/workspace/my_client_library,type=bind,consistency=cached"
   ]
}
```

and

```
# .devcontainer/Dockerfile
# Use the official openapi-generator-cli Docker image as the base image
FROM openapitools/openapi-generator-cli:latest

# Set the PATH environment variable to include openapi-generator-cli
ENV PATH="/usr/local/bin:${PATH}"
```

However when the container is built, the following command

```
openapi-generator-cli --version
```

returns a "command not found" in the terminal. And a quick search in /usr/bin and /usr/local/bin confirms that it's not in there. So where is it? What am I missing ?

Thanks in advance

Edit :

So I've found a directory openapi-generator-cli inside /opt/openapi-generator/modules, which I then tried to add to PATH, but with no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your docker file:

```
# Install OpenJDK and other dependencies for openapi-generator-cli
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jdk maven

# Download and install the openapi-generator-cli
RUN curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/master/bin/utils/openapi-generator-cli.sh -o /usr/local/bin/openapi-generator-cli \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/openapi-generator-cli

# Set environment variable for the openapi-generator-cli version
ENV OPENAPI_GENERATOR_VERSION 5.3.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it worked ! I just had to add an image in the 1st line : `FROM ubuntu` , as well as `apt-get -y install curl && apt-get -y install jq` in the first RUN. It must be possible to find an image that already contains them both, go ahead if you have a suggestion. If you make those changes I'll accept your answer :)